Persistent MySQL connection issues with FastAPI deployed on DigitalOcean and Azure
I have deployed a FastAPI application on DigitalOcean droplets and Azure App Service, with MySQL databases hosted on DigitalOcean and Azure respectively. Despite several attempts to mitigate the issue, I am consistently facing database connection problems, resulting in errors like:
2024-06-06T07:27:13.243707191Z: [ERROR] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 759, in _write_bytes
2024-06-06T07:27:13.243710391Z: [ERROR] raise err.OperationalError(
2024-06-06T07:27:13.243713391Z: [ERROR] sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))")

2024-05-21T12:03:39.909286838Z: [ERROR] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 692, in _read_packet
2024-05-21T12:03:39.909290038Z: [ERROR] packet_header = self._read_bytes(4)
2024-05-21T12:03:39.909293038Z: [ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-05-21T12:03:39.909296338Z: [ERROR] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 738, in _read_bytes
2024-05-21T12:03:39.909299638Z: [ERROR] raise err.OperationalError(
2024-05-21T12:03:39.909303838Z: [ERROR] pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query ([Errno 110] Connection timed out)')

The issue occurs intermittently, causing disruptions to my application. Here are the steps I've taken to address it:

Added middleware to handle database connections.
Configured Azure settings to "Open to all host (*)".
Set pool_pre_ping=True in the create_engine() function.
Appended ?connect_timeout=10&read_timeout=30&write_timeout=30 to the database URL.
Implemented db_session.close() in a finally block to ensure connections are properly closed.

Despite these efforts, the problem persists. I previously encountered similar issues with a Flask application on DigitalOcean, which were mitigated by explicitly closing database connections at the end of each API route. However, this approach is not feasible for my current FastAPI setup.
Details:

FastAPI version: 0.90.0
SQLAlchemy version: 2.0.2
Python version: 3.11

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve these MySQL connection issues in FastAPI deployments on DigitalOcean and Azure would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Code Structure:

main.py

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

from routers import *


app = FastAPI()
origins = ['*']


app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins     = origins,
    allow_credentials = True,
    allow_methods     = ["*"],
    allow_headers     = ["*"],
)


app.include_router(user.router)


app/database.py

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f"mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pwrd}@{host}:{port}/{name}"
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = (
    f"mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pwrd}@{host}:{port}/{name}"
    "?connect_timeout=10&read_timeout=30&write_timeout=30"
)

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, pool_pre_ping = True)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit = False, autoflush = False, bind = engine)

Base = declarative_base()


def get_db():
    try:
        db_session = SessionLocal()
        yield db_session
    finally:
        db_session.close()


db_models/SQL_Models.py (contains all SQLAlchemy classes defining tables)

import sqlalchemy as db

from app.database import Base


class Table_1(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'Table_1'

    row_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)
    ...

from app.database import engine; Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


routers/routes.py

@router.get('/{student_id}')
async def get_student_details(
    student_id: int,
    db_session: Session = Depends(get_db), # Here I am handling database connection
    token: Union[str, None] = Header(default=None)
):

    students = db_session \
        .query(Students) \
        .filter(Students.student_id == student_id) \
        .first()

    return students

Note that I am using MySQL RDBMS.

The error that you are getting is a timeout error. You have set the timeout to 30 seconds.
It could be that the SQL statement is taking more than 30 seconds

Nope, in case of a deadlock, mysql returns at once saying deadlock was detected and a transaction was rolled back. There are other possibilities as well, like sql statement's length is longer than max packet size

If sql statement's length is longer than max packet size it should return error 1153

@Shadow thanks, deadlock should return error 1213

Unfortunately, mysql often "goes away" if the query is longer than the max packet size instead of returning the specific error message.

@Shadow I am sure majority (if not all) of my SQL statements takes less than 30 seconds.

You could forcing SQLAlchemy to reconnect after an hour with the pool_recycle argument:
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, pool_pre_ping=True, pool_recycle=3600)


Will try this! But is this an optimal solution? Why 1 hour and no other time period?

I think the default in MySQL is to drop connections that have been inactive for 8 hours, so you could probably choose a slightly larger value. But, unless the application has super high load all the time, I usually prefer to be cautious
